# WordPress search of posts by month and year

Tags: wordpress, url, search-form

I have a search form with the following fields:

- search input
- month number drop down named "monthnum"
- year drop down named "year"
- sort by drop down

This is my wp_query

```
$args = array (
              's' => (!empty($_REQUEST["search"])?$_REQUEST["search"]:''),
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'post_status' =>'publish',
              'cat' => 5,
              'posts_per_page' => 9,
              'paged'                  => $paged,
              'monthnum' =>(!empty($_GET["monthnum"])?$_GET["monthnum"]:''),
              'year' => (!empty($_GET["year"])?$_GET["year"]:''),
              'orderby' =>(!empty($_GET["orderby"])?$_GET["orderby"]:'date'),
              'order' => (!empty($_GET["order"])?$_GET["order"]:'DSCE'),
            );
```

when I select a month and year I get an  404 Not Found and the end of the URL looks like this

```
?search=&monthnum=10&year=2016
```

when I hard code the month and year in the wp_query it works and displays the correct post
so why is it not working when I pass the month and year through the URL?
and how do I let the user search for post by month and year?

Comment: You should grab `$_GET['monthnum']` and `'year'`  with `get_query_var('monthnum');` and `get_query_var('year');`

Comment: `get_query_var('monthnum')` didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

the 'monthnum' field accepts int values you can't pass '' to it. try this code -

```
$args = array (
          's' => (!empty($_REQUEST["search"])?$_REQUEST["search"]:''),
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' =>'publish',
          'cat' => 5,
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged' => $paged,
          (!empty($_GET["monthnum"])?'monthnum' =>$_GET["monthnum"]:false),
          (!empty($_GET["year"]))?'year' => $_GET["year"]:false),
          'orderby' =>!empty($_GET["orderby"])?$_GET["orderby"]:'date',
        );
```

Comment: This query causes an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

Comment: Still same error, the problem was not on `'paged' => $paged` I fixed that before trying the code

Comment: `$args = array (
              's' => (!empty($_REQUEST["search"])?$_REQUEST["search"]:''),
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'post_status' =>'publish',
              'cat' => 5,
              'posts_per_page' => 9,
              'paged' => $paged,
              'order' =>(!empty($_GET["order"])?$_GET["order"]:'DSCE'),
            );
if(!empty($_GET["monthnum"])){$args['monthnum']=$_GET["monthnum"];}
if(!empty($_GET["year"])){$args['year']=$_GET["year"];}
if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])){$args['orderby']=$_GET["orderby"];} `

Comment: this gets me back to the same problem 
when I select a month and a year it shows 
404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Oh I had this same problem I think, for me what solved it was monthnum and year are reserved terms for the params. If you change them to something else it should solve it. I know this is an old post but maybe it will help someone else out.